# Wp redirect to url with ampersand string

Tags: wp-query, wp-redirect

i have a url like this:

```
www.url.ui/?keyone=valueone&keytwo=valuetwo&ekythree=valuethree
```

stored in a variable:

```
$url = www.url.ui/?keyone=valueone&keytwo=valuetwo&keythree=valuethree
```

I use `wp_redirect( $url )` to redirect to the url, but the problem is that after the redirect the url in the browser looks like this:

```
www.url.ui/?keyone=valueone&keytwo=valuetwo&amp;keythree=valuethree
```

This is how a create the url above:

```
$param = keyone=valueone&keytwo=valuetwo&keythree=valuethree
$url .= '?' . $param;
```

So function itself looks like this:

```
function redirect(){
    $url = www.url.ui/;
    $param = keyone=valueone&keytwo=valuetwo&keythree=valuethree
    $url .= '?' . $param;
    wp_redirect( $url )
}
```

So the function itself works fine, but the redirected url does not look like expected.
I already tried `wp_sanatize_redirect()` and the php function `urlencode` but neither of them results in what i need.

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with the url? What you said you have and what it looks like are the same, and it looks like a valid query string. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Anyway, you should pass the url through [`esc_url_raw()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw) before using it for redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing I see in Core would do that in either [`wp_redirect()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1165) or [`wp_sanitize_redirect()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1210) (which is used by  `wp_redirect()`). However...

1. [both functions are pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) and so could have been replaced by
   theme or plugin code.
2. And `wp_redirect()` has the `wp_redirect` filter that can be used to
   alter the redirect location-- the part you are having trouble with.
   Something could be causing trouble.

I don't know how to guess at which of those two are the problem.